# Facebook Login in sitecore

Tags: facebook, sitecore, facebook-c#-sdk, sitecore-social-connected

I am new to sitecore and currently working on it. I am not using the Social Connected module on sitecore for I don't have the module to install and I can't download it (I am using default modules and default sitecore. it was given to me by the company)

They have a requirement so that their website is facebook connected. I followed the tutorial in [here](http://csharpsdk.org) and I can retrieve email address to register the new user with the site.

I tried to log-in in the site with given email from facebook, but I don't have any password so that I can't log in using the connected user.

**My problem:** How can I connect the sitecore log-in with facebook login? So that everytime a user log in to my site using facebook, it will be logged in automatically just like another user that use default membership on sitecore.

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is exactly what the Social Connected module does... so I would really suggest you use that.

But if that is totally out of the question, you can log in a Sitecore user by just its username like this:

```
Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.Login("username_here");
```

Comment: I would like to use that, as fact I would love to, because it will ease my work, but the operational procedure on my client just to use that one little module is so many and so complex! I even have to rename all namespaces and things there. So, if I can log in using username only, can I use email only?

Comment: So, I was looking at the method, and I use this `Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.Login(Sitecore.Security.Accounts.UserManager.GetUsers().Single(o => o.Profile.Email.Equals(result.email)));`

Answer (score 0):

As said by Ruud, this can be achieved by using the social connected module.
This blog post should be helpful too: [Social Connected with Sitecore (Facebook) 1: Setup & Posting messages](http://techmusingz.wordpress.com/2014/07/03/social-connected-with-sitecore-facebook-1-setup-posting-messages/)